# Doesn't mahāyāna have a classification for jhānas?

Tags: meditation, mahayana, meditation-practicalities, jhana, vajrayana

Is it me or is it incredibly difficult to find resources [on the 4 (or 8, with the arupas) jhānas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhy%C4%81na_in_Buddhism#The_jh%C4%81nas) and how to reach them in the mahāyāna/vajrayāna literature? Apart from vague references to samādhi in general, I can't find anything.

**Edit:** In addition to the suttas, theravādins also have commentaries and books on jhānas, for example the one by Ajahn Brahm... I was looking for a mahāyāna equivalent, too bad :(

**Edit 2:** I've found my happiness: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1559393254](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1559393254)

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out part 2 of this book, it goes over exactly what you are looking for:  [https://www.amazon.com/Meditative-States-Tibetan-Buddhism-Rinpoche/dp/086171119X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/086171119X)

Also, this one, although this may be too difficult: [https://www.amazon.com/Mahamudra-Moonlight-Quintessence-Mind-Meditation/dp/0861712994](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0861712994)

This one I did not read, but it is written by the most respected lineage holder: [https://www.amazon.com/Practice-Tranquillity-Insight-Buddhist-Meditation/dp/1559391065](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1559391065)

Also, this: [https://www.amazon.com/Calm-Abiding-Special-Insight-Transformation/dp/1559391103](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1559391103)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! It reassures me to see that the first book talks about the 8 absorptions. It's less accessible than Ajahn Brahm on the other hand haha, I can't imagine the one you say is difficult!

Comment: I also found this btw https://www.amazon.com/Study-Practice-Meditation-Interpretations-Concentrations/dp/1559393254 I'm reading it and it's more accessible

Answer (score 1):

You're right - jhanas are deemphasized (and for good reason as far as I'm concerned), but don't forget that most Mahayana schools use the Chinese Agamas as a part of their canonical literature.  The Agamas do contain, more or less, the original Sutta-pitaka along with the vinaya, abhidhamma, etc.  You're not finding anything in the newer Mahayana literature because the Mahayanists are just using a Chinese translation of the same texts a Theravadan might refer to.

Comment: Yes, but theravādins also have commentaries and books on jhānas, for example the one by Ajahn Brahm... I was looking for a mahāyāna equivalent, too bad :(

Comment: Are you looking for a guide to jhana practice specifically from a Mahayana perspective? If so, I'm afraid you're going to be disappointed. Even the books Andrei mentioned don't follow the same paradigm as you'd find in the Theravadan tradition. I personally find the Theravadan approach to be a bit too mechanical and the language overly specific and technical. What you find in Vajrayana and Zen just feels more natural to me; but different strokes for different folks. If you are just looking for a guide to meditation, however, there are plenty.  My personal favorite is Zen Training by Sekida.